# Python Regular Expression for Stripping Terms

Tags: python

I want to strip terms with these rules:
strip all characters from left except alphanumeric characters
strip all characers from right except apostrophe and alphanumeric characters
I used `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip` functions:

```
term = term.lstrip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
term = term.rstrip(punctuations + string.whitespace)
```

I think this can be done in one line by using regular expression. How can I do that

Comment: You can use `str.lstrip()` and `str.rstrip()` in one line, too, just string them together: `your_string.lstrip(characters).rstrip(characters)`.

Comment: For creating regular Expressions you can use [RegEx Pal](https://www.regexpal.com/) and [python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> By Python definition '\W == [^a-zA-Z0-9_], which excludes all numbers,
>   letters and _

```
>>> import re, string
>>> pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')
>>> stringe1="    hi bye hithisitstesing 8909 okay left "
>>> pattern.sub('', stringe1.lstrip())
'hibyehithisitstesing8909okayleft'
```

another example:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Kl13@£$%[};'\""
>>> pattern = re.compile('\W')
>>> string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
>>> print string
Kl13
```